# Does Mn always exist in Photosystem II?

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

I had the impression that PSII (photosystem II) always has four Manganese atoms 
(4 Mn). Is there any reason that these atoms are needed?

Is Mn or Fe also present in bacteria LH1 or LH2?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding your question... can you write everything out and not use abbreviations? This will help. Thanks!

Comment: I have wrote EVERYTHING out i.e. PSII is photosystem II, and Manganese is Mn.....what else? LH is light harvesting

Comment: Mn Fe are standard chemical symbols while PS2 is also standard abbreviation. Please stop these politics. Thanks.

Comment: I made some edits to your title because the previous isn't in the correct english syntax

Comment: I guess you are referring to Magnesium and not Manganese. Are you sure you are talking about manganese?

Comment: Thanks. I am not a native speaker. Therefore, my English surely have some problem. But manganese....I guess was copied from a paper....But what is really there?

Comment: Briefest answer; Yes, Manganese (Mn) atoms are part of [Water splitting complex or OEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen-evolving_complex)

Comment: Is Fe also part of Water splitting complex or OEC ?

Comment: Could this Mn be replaced by other atoms like Zn or Fe

Answer (score 2):

Manganese is part of the oxygen-evolving complex and is essentiell for the oxidation of the water to generate electrons, protons and oxygen. This is done by changing the oxidation state of the mangane from +2 to +4, as shown in the figure (from [here](http://www.life.illinois.edu/crofts/bioph354/lect25.html)):

[image]

These manganese atoms are the center of the reaction - important here are the different oxidation states they can take, other examples are copper (in tyrosinase for example) or iron (hemoglobin) which are also present in the active center of enzymes.
For more information see references 1 and 2.

Anoxygenic bacterial photosynthesis also needs metal ions in the bacteriochlorophyll, this is magnesium (as in the chlorophyll of green plants), the light harvesting complexes contain iron-sulphur complexes.
For a general overview see reference 3, for more detail on the reaction centers and their evolution, see reference 4.

References:

1. [Where water is oxidized to dioxygen: structure of the photosynthetic
   Mn<sub>4</sub>Ca cluster.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17082458)
2. [Reduction-induced inhibition and Mn(II) release from the photosystem
   II oxygen-evolving complex by hydroquinone or NH2OH are consistent
   with a Mn(III)/Mn(III)/Mn(IV)/Mn(IV) oxidation state for the
   dark-adapted enzyme.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15697239)
3. [Bacterial Photosynthesis](http://photobiology.info/Jones.html)
4. [Reaction centres: the structure and evolution of biological solar
   power.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.522.2268&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: There seems to have some LH1 or LH2 do not need such atoms. I am not sure whether PS I or PS II...

Comment: any physical reason why these atoms must be there? (for instance they need a spin or entropy...)

Comment: @latra Besides having the function as electron acceptors/donors? Not that I know of.

Comment: So, it is biochemistry instead of biophysics. The picture above came from a biophysics course note.

Comment: @latra If you want to see the real flow of the electrons on the molecular level, this is mixed biochemistry-biophysics.

Comment: Yes, I indeed want to see the real flow of ....photon...perhaps also electron...But is it possible?

Comment: what is wrong with the fourth paper ?  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968000401020345   i got only junk codes

Comment: @latra I don't know, it worked. I have updated this to a different source, which should be ok.

Comment: no...the same...the title, the abstract, the figure caption and the section heading...are all in Greek letters........

Comment: You said in the above that Mn is the center of reaction. I think you are talking about type I RC. Only type I RC contains Mn.